# PodioError: File uploads are only supported on the server right now

Tags: javascript, crm, podio

I am getting an error while uploading file into Podio, not quite sure what it means. The response says:

> {message: "File uploads are only supported on the server right now."
>   name: "PodioError", status:undefined, url:undefined}

I am using [podio-js](https://github.com/podio/podio-js) library.

Answer (score 0):

The key part of the error is `url: undefined` which would indicate that the URL for the file you wish to upload has not been assigned to the url parameter.

Comment: I am wondering whether the error message means we can't upload files using API currently.